# Sum $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine the limit of the sum

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2/2^k$

Doing the convergence test shows the sum converges $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)^2/2^{k+1}}{k^2/2^k} = 1/2$ so there must be a solution, but the normal tricks used to solve geometric series or telescoping series don't seem to work.

Comment: Hint: Telescope the sum of $$\frac{k^2}{2^k}=\frac{(k-1)^2+4(k-1)+6}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{k^2+4k+6}{2^k}.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that by just differentiating

$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ with respect to $x$ and by multiplying by $x$, we get the identity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x} , \quad |x|<1,\tag3$$ differentiating once more and multiplying by $x$ gives, as $n \to \infty$, **using $|x|<1$:**
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^k=\frac{x (1+x)}{(1-x)^3} , \quad |x|<1,\tag4$$
then put $x:=\dfrac12$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2/2^k \longrightarrow 6, \quad \text{as} \, n \to \infty.
$$

Comment: I wouldn't have come to the idea of differentiating like this, very elegant!

Answer (score 8):

Let
$$ S = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2}{2^k}. $$
Then:
$$ 2S = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2}{2^{k-1}} = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(k+1)^2}{2^k},$$
hence:
$$ S = 2S-S = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{2k+1}{2^k} = 2+2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k}{2^k}$$
but with the same technique, by letting $T=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k}{2^k}$, we have:
$$ T=2T-T = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^k} = 2$$
from which $S=\color{red}{6}$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is find the function $f(r)$ such that $$\dfrac{r^2}{2^r}=f(r-1)-f(r)$$ which is of the form $\dfrac{1}{2^r}\left(Ar^2+Br+C\right).$ Then easily you can find the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{2^k}$and take the limit $n\to\infty.$

Another way to do this is use the identity $$1+x+x^2+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{1-x},\,\,\,\,|x|\lt 1.$$ Differentiate this power series multiply once by $x$ and again differentiate. Then you have the required answer.

Comment: Also this is an special [arithmetico geometric series.](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArithmetico-geometric_sequence&ei=yNIYVZ2lKMSB8QWv4oHQAg&usg=AFQjCNE_T1HEGPyHSVxwGXXLyj5jo-DMAQ)